# linux command to delete the last column of csv

Tags: linux, csv

How can I write a linux command to delete the last column of tab-delimited csv?

**Example input**

> aaa bbb ccc ddd
>   111 222 333 444

**Expected output**

> aaa bbb ccc
>   111 222 333

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What responses did you get? Sheeesh guy.... show that you at least did a little work on your own!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to remove the fist field instead of the last. So we reverse the content, remove the first field, and then revers it again.

Here is an example for a "CSV"

```
rev file1 | cut -d "," -f 2- | rev
```

Replace the "file1" and the "," with your file name and the delimiter accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` for this.  You specify a delimiter with option `-d` and then give the field numbers (option `-f`) you want to have in the output.  Each line of the input gets treated individually:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f 1-6 < my.csv > new.csv
```

This is according to your words.  Your example looks more like you want to strip a column in the middle:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f 1-3,5-7 < my.csv > new.csv
```

The `$'\t'` is a `bash` notation for the string containing the single tab character.

Comment: @downvoter Please comment on what you didn't like about this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command which will delete the last column of tab-delimited csv irrespective of field numbers,

```
sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'
```

for example:

```
echo "aaa bbb ccc ddd 111 222 333 444" | sed -r 's/(.*)\s+[^\s]+$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d ',' -f 1-3 inpyt.csv > output.csv
```

Where -d is followed by a separator, which is a comma in a csv file.
Where -f is followed by the reserved columns, that is, columns 1 to 3.